# How to access host docker instance from docker container

Tags: docker

**The Problem:**
Let's say you need to be able to create containers in your host from inside a container, Why?!!! Imagine you have your "continuous everything" process automated in a *Jenkins Pipeline* and this process includes creation of container or services for testing.

Even Though container and virtual machines enforces isolation from the host, this is a valid scenario.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:**
Sorry WinTel guys, did you expect this answer includes Windows?... Well just a clue, you can enable tcp://localhost:2375

Coming back to production grade answer, follow the next steps:

1. Spin up your instance binding "/var/run/docker.sock" from your host to your container:

   ```
   docker container run --name container -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock image
   ```
2. docker.sock as any file exposes its user id and group id, any user having as group "docker" is allowed to "talk" with docker using the client, so run the following script:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   DOCKER_SOCKET=/var/run/docker.sock
   DOCKER_GROUP=docker

   if [ -S ${DOCKER_SOCKET} ]; then
   DOCKER_GID=$(stat -c '%g' ${DOCKER_SOCKET})
   groupadd -for -g ${DOCKER_GID} ${DOCKER_GROUP}
   usermod -aG ${DOCKER_GROUP} youruser
   fi
   ```

> Don't freak out, this won't harm your system, basically, if the file (socket) 
>    docker.sock exists (as it should), the script will get it group id, will create a group call 
>    docker and will set the same group id as the docker's group one in the host 
>    (confused?!?!, remember that we are inside the container we want to have access 
>    to host docker, we executed *"docker container exec -it -u root container bash"* 
>    in order to access the container), then, the user called *"youruser"* will be 
>    modified by being added to *"docker"* group.

3. (*Almost there!!!*) Install docker client inside your container, use your 
   favorite package manager and install the docker client, I have the same version 
   of client and server and works like a charm but I suppose I could work with 
   other versions but come on!! mixing versions??? seriously???

> After following these steps, you will be able to run docker commands using the common process, just remember that it is possible to do anything!!! even shooting you in the foot!!!